# What is "PTC Mathcad Viewable Support"?

Tags: installation

I'm going to install the Matcad Prime (v3.1) demo/freeware. The installer has two main components but there's no description in it of what the "PTC Mathcad Viewable Support" part does... nor does googling the term find much useful info on its purpose (other than it [can fail to install](https://www.ptcusercommunity.com/thread/51038)). So, does anyone know what it does?

[image]

Note partial answer below from the documentation. To get that, I should have clicked on the top-right question mark... which gets me to the pdf installation guide, which says (on page 15)

> PTC Mathcad Viewable Support—Installs a component that enables PTC
>   Mathcad when integrated with Windchill to generate PDF rendering of the
>   worksheet. This component is required when using Windchill integration.

They could have made that more obvious with some in-app help. Still I don't know exactly what "Windchill" is... apparently some "Workgroup Manager" also made by PTC. It's still unclear to me if I also need that "Windchill" for PDF export/generation or if Mathcad with that "viewable support" alone does that... they seem to make it hard get a simple answer to such simple questions. Also, very amusingly, there's a [550-page book on Mathcad 3.0 Prime](https://books.google.com/books?id=QUMTAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Essential+PTC+Mathcad%C2%AE+Prime%C2%AE+3.0&hl=en&sa=X&q=pdf&f=false)... which never mentions this pdf [export] thing. So, if someone already knows what this "viewable" bit actually does [exports to pdf by itself, or do I also need that Windchill for that to work??]... please let me know. Also, it'a not a new feature in 3.1, or at least is not mentioned in the ["what's new in 3.1 leaflet"](http://www.root-solutions.co.uk/assets/PDF/mathcad-prime-3.1-whats-new.pdf).

Comment: I think what's going on here is that PTC Mathcad Viewable Support does such a crappy job of exporting to PDF, that Mathcad Prime deliberately did a rubbish job of the documentation of this feature so they can blame the bad results on their users.